# Running zookeeper with even number of nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

While running zookeeper on a 6 node cluster, does anyone know if the quorum is automatically determined to be 4 nodes or 3 nodes?

If the quorum is chosen as N/2, then it would become 3 and can lead to a split brain situation.
If the quorum is chosen as (N+1)/2, then it would become 4 and will avoid the split brain situation.

So I am hoping that it is the latter but the [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/zookeeperStarted.html) does not mention anything of that sort.
Does anyone know this for sure?

P.S. I know that odd number of zookeeper nodes is recommended but I am just curious to know what happens for an even number of nodes case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.flexible.QuorumMaj.java

```
public boolean containsQuorum(HashSet<Long> set)
{
    return set.size() > n / 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So the `greater-than` sign does mean that the quorum is chosen as (n+1)/2 and an even-numbered zookeeper would not fall in a split brain situation. Specifically, in our case of 6 nodes, the quorum condition becomes `set.size > 3` which implies atleast 4 nodes quorum.

Answer (score 3):

Having an even number of nodes doesn't add any advantage when nodes go down/fail.
A 6 node cluster can tolerate up to 2 node failures, meaning it needs at least 4 nodes to avoid the split-brain problems or get the majority vote. which can even be achieved with 5 nodes cluster, meaning 5 nodes cluster also can tolerate up to 2 nodes failure.

So, adding one additional node is just an operational cost.

I have answered the same question in my blog.

Please have a look :)
[Why Zookeeper has odd number of nodes?](https://medium.com/@bikas.katwal10/why-zookeeper-needs-an-odd-number-of-nodes-bb8d6020e9e9)

Comment: Why we don't use 2 nodes instead of 3 ?

Example :
n = 2;
2/2 + 1 = 2
which means toleration failure is 0 ? (2-2)

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but replying for the sake of other who might stumble onto this post.

Zookeeper needs a majority nodes to be up and communicating. So in your case it would be 4 out of 6 which is why odd numbers are used. Isn't one of your nodes redundant from a HA point of view? if 3 nodes go down your cluster is down. same with a 5 node cluster.